# How do I find $E[X_1|X_1<X_2]$ when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables?

Tags: probability

What property of Gaussians do I have to exploit to solve this?

Comment: Why the close vote? "unclear what you're asking"??

Comment: The question is extremely clear to me...and it was promptly answered. I edited the text to be more specific about what kind of help I was looking for and the question is still on hold. What am I missing??

Comment: I've no idea why this question was close as "unclear what you're asking", it's totally clear to me. I can only suggest that you edit it to elaborate it a little, basically including the title text in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sketch of solution.

$X_1 = \frac{1}{2}(X_1 - X_2) + \frac{1}{2}(X_1 + X_2)$, where $X_1 + X_2$ is independent of $X_1 - X_2$(they combined together are Gaussian vector and they have zero correlation)

$E(X_1 |X_1 - X_2 < 0) = \frac{1}{2}E(X_1 - X_2 | X_1 -X_2 < 0) + \frac{1}{2}E(X_1 + X_2) = -\frac{1}{2}E|\mathcal{N}(0,2)|$

Comment: Thank you. I guess there is no easy way to get the numerical answer...

Comment: @mathzat in fact the exact answer is $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}E|N(0,1)|$ and $E|N(0,1)| = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Comment: Cool. Got it. Perhaps a better reference is for the Half Normal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).